# Htaccess - Where is the error

Tags: .htaccess

I am not able to find the error in the following Htaccess Code.
Isn't it just a simple 301 redirection?

```
Redirect 301 flaechenformeln.html http://www.mathespass.at/formeln/flaechenformeln.php
```

I have also tried to change the redirect a bit, but it is not working.
But however this works:

```
Redirect 301 /testversion/klasse2/index.html  http://www.mathespass.at/testversion/klasse2/index.php
```

Isn't it the same?

Hope you can help me!
With best greetings

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error, it is not working, there is no redirect

Comment: the file flaechenformeln.html is in the main direction, do I have to do something special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` directive performs starting string match of the `REQUEST_URI` with the given pattern and it must start with a `/`.

Try this rule instead:

```
Redirect 301 /flaechenformeln.html http://www.mathespass.at/formeln/flaechenformeln.php
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. You have saved my day ;-)